Why eclipse through an error about incompatible version while they are compatible versions?
I am learning Java, I wanted to install JavaFX in the eclipse, so I can create applications.
Version of JavaFX SDK: 21.0.4
JDK version: 22.0.2
I asked chatGPT hoe to install javaFX and did every step and it worked on my pc, I can run my application.
However I tried to do exactly the same thing on the laptop and it through mistake about incompatibility. Why? I checked multiple times that laptop and pc have the same versions of sdk and javaFX. The only difference is that on laptop I have eclipse 2022-03 and on pc I have eclipse 2024-06. What the problem?
This is an error from my laptop when I try to launch my application:
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\Andrii\javafx-sdk-21.0.4\lib\javafx.base.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Unsupported major.minor version 61.0
I also tried to install javaFX in other way like in that video below:
https://youtu.be/nz8P528uGjk?si=Nhh1Aug_VjwVQu5o
However it through the same error. I have no idea what the problem is.

If it threw an exception about the class version 61.0 being incompatible, it's probably because you're running on older version of Java on the laptop, even though you think it's running JDK 22. How are you running the application on the laptop? Are you running it from the command line or from Eclipse? It might be that Eclipse is using whatever version of the JDK it comes with, even though you've installed a later version separately.

"I asked chatGPT hoe" don't call chatGPT that, it is impolite.

@talexmovedtoCodidact - Well ... there's lots of things ChatGPT will do for money.  Just saying ... :-)

@StephenC I never said he was wrong. Just impolite.
